# Adding a dynamic row into an existing html with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to add new ROWS and COLUMNS into another existing TABLE within the same page. How could I do that easily?

Here is the code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsubjecschedule ORDER BY Subject");
$i=0;
$b =1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Subject']."<input type='hidden' name='subj[$i]' value=".$row['Subject']."></td>
    <td>".$row['Lec']."<br/>".$row['Lab']."<input type='hidden' name='leclab[$i]' value=".$row['Lec']."><input type='hidden' name='lab[$i]' value=".$row['Lab']."></td>
    <td>".$row['Descriptive']."<input type='hidden' name='desc[$i]' value=".$row['Descriptive']."></td>
    <td>".$row['Day']."<br/>".$row['Labday']."<input type='hidden' name='daylabday[$i]' value=".$row['Day']."><input type='hidden' name='labday[$i]' value=".$row['Labday']."></td>

    <td>".$row['LecTime']."<br/>".$row['LabTime']."<input type='hidden' name='lectlabt[$i]' value=".$row['LecTime']."><input type='hidden' name='labtime[$i]' value=".$row['LabTime']."></td>
    <td>".$row['Room']."<br/>".$row['Labroom']."<input type='hidden' name='roomlabroom[$i]' value=".$row['Room']."><input type='hidden' name='labroom[$i]' value=".$row['Labroom']."></td>
    <td><input id='send' name='reserv[$i]' type='submit' value='Add' [$b] /></td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
 <table border="1" style='width: 900px;'>

<thead>
<tr>
    <th>SubjectCode <th>Units <th>Time <th>Day <th>Room</th> 
</tr>
</thead>
```

and this is where I display the data but it displays one row only

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['reserv'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['reserv'])){
            $i = current(array_keys($_POST['reserv']));
            $subj=$_POST['subj'][$i];
            $leclab=$_POST['leclab'][$i];
            $lab=$_POST['lab'][$i];
            $labday=$_POST['labday'][$i];
            $desc=$_POST['desc'][$i];
            $daylab=$_POST['daylabday'][$i];
            $lectlabt=$_POST['lectlabt'][$i];
            $labtime=$_POST['labtime'][$i];
            $roomLabroom=$_POST['roomlabroom'][$i];
            $labroom=$_POST['labroom'][$i];
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['reserv'])){
        $count=0;
        $a=0;
        $c=current(array_keys($_POST['reserv']));
        if (!empty($c)){
            $a=1;
            for ($count;$count<=$a;$count++){
                echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$subj."</td>
                  <td>".$leclab."<br/>".$lab."</td>
                  <td>".$lectlabt."<br/>".$labtime."</td>
                  <td>".$daylab."<br/>".$labday."</td>
                  <td>".$roomLabroom."<br/>".$labroom."</td>
                  </tr>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you check the value of `$a`? for ($count;$count<=$a;$count++){

Comment: the value of $a is 1 but it display 2 rows with the same value

Comment: did you forgot to close the **<th>** tags in your code in the second table or it's just a typo while writing here?

Comment: oh didn't notice! i use click event to add another row but when i click it display one row only

Comment: is both the code section at same page? because if you post the second row from your query loop how could you maintain the previous html/inserted records in that table. it's batter to use the session variable or jquery/javascript to add rows while click on that row.

Comment: Yes sir is in the same page.i think i get it now sir  thank you for your reply.

Comment: how can i use session variables? sorry i just confuse what to do.

Comment: To use session variables, define those with $_SESSION. [Take a look](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: why are you doing this with php (is any specific reqquirement to use php) because it's quite easy to use jquery to add the clicked element to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

dude as it enter the loop

```
for ($count;$count<=$a;$count++)
```

value 0f a=1 and count=0

now first it executes when count=0 and den again wen count=1 bt all dis time value of a remains same that is a=1

now wen count=2 count<=1 (false)

dats why onie 2 rows are displayed

for every row u making different forms so wen submitted a form,data is submitted of one form and wen u run the iteration after post twice in the loop dat value comes two times